# RandomizedSearchCV - Sample from a grid that doesn't fit into int limit

Tags: python, types, scikit-learn, integer

When running the `.fit` method from `RandomizedSearchCV`, one of the operations is to check the length of the parameters.

For some of my tests, the size of this grid is bigger than the parameter size.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

```
--> 332     grid_size = len(ParameterGrid(self.param_distributions))
    333     return min(self.n_iter, grid_size)
    334 else:

OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

Comment: You have bigger problems if the grid size is larger than integer size, have you ever thought how much time it would take to evaluate all parameter combinations?

Comment: I'm aware of that, which is why the question is about the Random Search... which does fit my specific use case. A good warning to have on this question regardless, thank you

Comment: I have to say, it's unusual to see a question about "int limit" under Python.  One of the more amazing things about Python is that it has unlimited size integers.  In your case of course the limit is imposed by the package you're using, not Python itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code surrounding the snippet from your traceback, we can see that the full `ParameterGrid` is created when the `param_distributions` consists entirely of lists instead of scipy(-compatible) distributions.  So an easy workaround is to just use a scipy distribution for at least one of your parameters (maybe `randint` for a discrete uniform distribution, to emulate the list version of the parameter grid; or some hyperparameter that doesn't actually matter, like a `random_state`).

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work? I get the following error: `TypeError: Parameter grid for parameter 'int' needs to be a list or a numpy array, but got <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object at 0x7fcced7ddd60> (of type rv_frozen) instead. Single values need to be wrapped in a list with one element.`

Comment: @GooJ I've used scipy distributions for random searches before, but I can try again. If you can update the Question with a MWE, it would help to be sure the original issue gets resolved.

Comment: @GooJ That error message appears in `ParameterGrid`, but with a scipy distribution that should never be generated, I think.  A toy example with a scipy distribution as a parameter space runs for me.